# Logical Error in my C Code

Tags: c

I am a beginner, just learning C; so, please be patient with me.

I am trying to write a very simple program that goes through a string, counts the characters in each word, and then replaces those words with the number of their characters. My problem is that I am stuck in an infinite loop and cannot figure out why! Here is the code:

```
#define NEWLINE '\n'
#define SPACE ' '

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int character;
  int count = 0;

  printf("\nType in a sentence of any lenght, then hit ENTER!\n");
  character = getchar();

  while (character != NEWLINE) {

     while ((character != SPACE)  || (character != NEWLINE)) {
        count++;
        character = getchar();
     }

  printf("%d ", count); 
  count = 0;

  if (character != NEWLINE) {
     character = getchar();
     }
  }  

 printf("\n");
 system("PAUSE"); 
 return 0;
 }
```

Thanks for everyone who helped me! I guess I go back and study logical operators a bit more.

Comment: Logical operators are not too hard to understand. Examples with them are often trivial at first hand. It's just when you apply them then you need to think what are they actually doing with my code. Which parts are involved and what am I setting the condition on. It often helps to go through it by hand when you're starting out, to understand what is happening at each iteration.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
while ((character != SPACE)  || (character != NEWLINE)) {
    count++;
    character = getchar();
}
```

this will loop infinitely because the inverse:

```
(character == SPACE)  && (character == NEWLINE)
```

will ALWAYS be false.

I suspect you mean

```
while ((character != SPACE)  && (character != NEWLINE)) {
    count++;
    character = getchar();
}
```

Comment: Yup, that fixed it. Thank you! I really need to get back to these logical operators and learn the crap out of them. :)

Answer (score 4):

You have an always true condition:

```
(character != SPACE)  || (character != NEWLINE)
```

eg:

```
character = ' ':  false or true => true
character = '\n': true or false => true
```

You should change it to:

```
(character != SPACE) && (character != NEWLINE)
```

That should fix your infinite loop.

Answer (score 2):

Replace the `||` With `&&`

Comment: !!  !!  !!  !!  !!  !!  !!  !!

Answer (score 1):

Replace the || (OR) with && (AND) because the while loop will always be true and for that reason it will never break out of the loop. It should work if you replace it.